# How long does CLLocationManager store previous (old) location in cache?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

Most of the time devs are asking how to filter old cached locations, however I'm interested in opposite thing - how to preserve and get old location :) Here's my case: I have weather screen in my app where I'm downloading weather forecasts for current location. As soon as the app starts, I'm starting standard location updates with 1km accuracy and saving received location in my locator class private member. If the app does not receive any location update then it needs to show any known previous location - like grabbing one out of [CLLocationManager location].

The problem is with iPad2. My app runs without device restart for about a week but [CLLocationManager location] returns nil very frequently. For example, I have opened google maps app yesterday on iPad and got the message "Cannot determine location", and so  [CLLocationManager location] returned nil in my app. Then I pressed location arrow icon in google maps app and then google maps app showed my current place. Also, [CLLocationManager location] returned some location in my app. However, the same problem persist today - [CLLocationManager location] returns nil again, so I guess CLLocationManager discards location cache after some time and if you are not moving with device then you will not get any known previous location. Any ideas how to workaround this and to force CLLocationManager to retrieve any location if it's nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location)

> The most recently retrieved user location. (read-only)
>
> *@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocation *location*
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.
>
> In iOS 4.0 and later, this property may contain a more recent location object at launch time. Specifically, if significant location updates are running and your application is terminated, this property is updated with the most recent location data when your application is relaunched (and you create a new location manager object). This location data may be more recent than the last location event processed by your application.
>
> It is always a good idea to check the timestamp of the location stored in this property. If the receiver is currently gathering location data, but the minimum distance filter is large, the returned location might be relatively old. If it is, you can stop the receiver and start it again to force an update.

It will store it in the *cache* for as long as possible, there isn't a timeout on it. It may set it to nil if something that used location services failed to get any location.

Comment: Very odd because location services are available all the time on my iPad, so there's nothing that could disallow to get new location.

Comment: Also should note, in order to detect such cases (when omething that used location services failed to get any location) we need to handle didFailed callback.